# How to duplicate a microsoft form using ms graph api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-forms, graph-explorer

I need a way to duplicate a Microsoft Form and get its link using the REST API of Microsoft - MS Graph. Is there a way to do that?

I have searched, but I have found no concrete information. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way of fetching the MS form details or Duplicate it using the MS graph api , If you want you can raise feature request for the same :
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform

For more reference to this :https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-forms/api-to-access-ms-forms/m-p/1463830

Hope this helps.